# Transfer electron app to cordova app

Tags: reactjs, cordova, webpack, redux, electron

I have a working electron application that uses React, Redux and WebPack. My current task is to create a working mobile Cordova application from it. What are the main steps I should undertake? How to import the bundle.js created by WebPack, what should I copy in the www folder. I have a very limited knowledge on Node and I will be very thankful for some guidance.

The boilerplate used for the electron application is:
https://github.com/chentsulin/electron-react-boilerplate.git

Answer (score 0):

You may have a look at [quasar-framework](https://quasar.dev). Although it's based on vue.js it provides wrappers for electron AND cordova.